# Unexpected behavior when reading a 5GB CSV file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a large (5GB) CSV file that I want to load into a `pandas.DataFrame`. I tried to run the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./original-utf8.csv')
```

But it yielded an error:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 92 fields in line 3098834, saw 163
```

I inspected the line `3098834 +/- 1` manually, and it was OK.

Then, I tried to ignore the offending lines:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./original-utf8.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

This time, I got a 23 warnings of the following style:

```
b'Skipping line 3098834: expected 92 fields, saw 163\n'
```

Seems like non of them is problematic.

In addition, the number of rows in the yielded `DataFrame` doesn't match the number of lines in the CSV file (even after taking into account the number of warnings). Seems like `pandas`(?) drops more lines without saying anything.

Any idea? How can I detect where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe a second pair of eyes will help.  Could you post line 3098834 +/- 1 so we can also see it?  Also, does your data include newlines inside of quoted fields?

Comment: I wish I could share it. Sorry, but this is impossible. There should not be any new lines in the quoted fields.

Comment: Any quoted fields that don't close properly?  I imagine that could eat up a number of lines.

Comment: The quoted lines are potential suspects. How can I easily check that?

Comment: "Sorry, but this is impossible" how is it impossible?

Comment: One possibility is to iterate over the file using Python's `csv` module checking each row for the right number of columns, then discarding the row.  As soon as you find one with the wrong number of columns, print it and print the line number.  Then break loop.

Comment: @PaulH The data is confidential and I cannot put it online.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Sounds like a good idea. Do you have some tips on using the `csv` module?

Comment: trim your file down to lines 3098834 +/- 5, confirm you still get an error, anonymize it, confirm you still get an error, then post it.

Comment: Nothing's impossible, for your own purposes the linux command 
**sed -n '3098834p' file | ** could help you out.

Comment: @Dror:  The docs are decent.  And there are plenty of good examples on StackOverflow.  Make sure you follow the docs for the version of Python you are using because there are some minor differences between Python 2 and Python 3 with respect to csv.  I recommend the `csv` module because it won't choke on variable length rows.

Comment: You could post your line without revealing data.  `''.join('x' if c.isalnum() else c for c in line)`.  So if your line was `'red, 10.7, "i, have, commas"'` it would be transformed to `'xxx, xx.x, "x, xxxx, xxxxxx"'`.  We could then see the structure of the line, but not the data.

Comment: I found several `^@` in the file. Seems like they caused the problem. Still, the annoying this is that there is a mismatch between the number of lines in the CSV (`wc -l foo.csv`) and the number of lines in the `DataFrame`. But this might turn to be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the same number of columns everywhere

```
awk -F, '{print NF}' file.csv | sort -u
```

If you get more than 1 result then it means the file isn't formatted properly.

Also, you can try loading the data like this

```
df=pd.read_csv("file.csv",nrows=3098834-1)
```

If that works you know the previous lines are good. Then you can try loading the file like this

```
df=pd.read_csv("file.csv",skiprows=3098834+2)
```

Comment: Good looks on the bash work for a python question, but this means you are neglecting at most 2 / 3,098,834 samples : )

Comment: Just wanted to make sure the file is formatted properly. I could of written that in python/pandas but its getting an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your five gig file is missing a newline...

```
 delim= ","
 a = []    
 f = open(file)
 text = f.read()
 text = text.split("\n")
 fields = len(text[0])
 c = 0
 for k in text:
     if( len(k.split(delim))==fields ):
         a.append(k[0:fields])
         a.append(["wonkyRow"+str(c)]+k[fields:len(k)]+[0]*(92-len(k)))
         c+=1
     else:
         a.append(k)
 df = pandas.df(data = [tuple(k) for k in a])
```